# Use Context API --react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Component 1:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { Component2 } from "./Component2.js";

 export const userContext = createContext();
 export default function App() {
 const [user, setUser] = useState("vk1");

 
return (
<div className="App">
  <userContext.provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
    <Component2 />
  </userContext.provider>
</div>
);
}
```

Component 2:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import userContext from "./App";

const Component2 = () => {
const { user, setUser } = useContext(userContext);
setUser("vkk");
return <h1>Hi i am from {user} component2</h1>;
};

export default Component2;
```

Component 3:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import  userContext from "./App";

const Component3 = () => {
const { user, setUser } = useContext(userContext);
setUser("vk");
return <h2>I am from {user} component3</h2>;
};

export default Component3;
```

Was expecting the state should be shared between the component but was getting the below error.

The element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: `import { Component2 } from "./Component2.js";` You're doing a named import, but you exported it as `export default Component2;` Change the import to `import Component2 from "./Component2.js";`

Comment: same issue persist even after changing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import is wrong**

change -> this  import { Component2 } from "./Component2.js" to this => import  Component2  from "./Component2.js"

As well as You have given incorrect words provider as userContext.provider  - it is "Provider"

Comment: even after correcting the code same issue persist i am running it on an online editor

Comment: please share whole code here , using codesandbox, I have edited ThemeContext.Provider this is how we wrap component.

Comment: after correcting the code it worked but ran into this error

Comment: Cannot destructure property 'user' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.@user12876817

Comment: Check How you are trying to export the context from file.